# pyinstaller program keeps running in background after closing

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have a pyinstaller executable wxpython GUI that works fine.  The only issue I am having is that when I close the program with the X button on the window, it stays running in the background.  Does anyone know of a way to kill the process when the window X button is clicked?

Comment: Are you using `self.Destroy()` when exiting?

Comment: I am when using the wx.Button.  This is happening when the user simply closes the window.  I am not sure how to link self.destroy with the window's close button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `Close` window event, which is `wx.EVT_CLOSE` like every other event i.e.:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
```

Then in you `OnExit(self,event)` use `self.Destroy()`
If that still doesn't work, you almost certainly have something still open. If you are unable to track that down, a workaround is using `sys.exit()` but that really should be frowned upon.

Comment: That did it, I had self.Close() instead of Destory() -- Thanks for the help